# Immediate invoking function inside build(context) returns Null(Flutter 2.0)

Tags: flutter, dart

For an Alert widget which has to be conditionally rebuilt every 3 seconds, on resetting the build state (_rebuild ) using an Immediate Invoking Function.

However the Immediate Invoking Function in which the Alert widget is wrapped
returns `Null`.

`Since build(context) only accepts Widgets`,is it even possible to  use  Immediate Invoking Function in  build(context) to alter conditional parameters?

ERROR

```
Column's children must not contain any null values, but a null value was found at index 1
```

CODE

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:async';

void main () => runApp(MaterialApp(
  theme: ThemeData.dark(),
  home: ConditionalWidgets(),
));


class ConditionalWidgets extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
_ConditionalWidgetsState createState() => _ConditionalWidgetsState();
}

class _ConditionalWidgetsState extends State<ConditionalWidgets> {
  bool   _reBuild = true ;
  int _counter = 0;


  void initState(){
    super.initState();

    _reBuildTimer();

  }


  void _reBuildTimer() {
    Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 3), (timer) {
      setState() {
           _counter++;
          _reBuild = true;
      }
    });
  }


  @override


  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body : Center(child:Column(
        children : [
            Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.all(50),
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(60),
                decoration:  BoxDecoration(
                  shape :BoxShape.rectangle,
                  border: Border.all(
                    color: Colors.orange,
                    width: 8,
                  ),
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                ),

              child:FittedBox(child: Text('Always Visible Widget', style: TextStyle()))),





// Conditional   _reBuild Alert - returns NUll
          if(  _reBuild)
            (){
              AlertDialog(
                  title: Text('Conditionally  Visible Widget'),
                  content: FittedBox(child: Text(
                      'Rebuild Count =  $_counter', style: TextStyle())));
                     print('_reBuild = $_reBuild');
                    _reBuild = false;//Reset   _reBuild using Immediate Invoking Function
            }()
        ],
      ),),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have something similar implemented for an app. I use streams to rebuild the widget
you can play with the code to get desired output

Alert Dialoge

```
showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (context) {
        return StreamBuilder(
            stream: bloc.eventStream,
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.data == Event.Success) {
                return AlertDialog(
                  scrollable: true,
                  content: Column(
                    children: [
                      Icon(
                        Icons.check_circle,
                        color: Colors.green[800],
                        size: 300,
                      ),
                      Text(
                        "Added Successfully !",
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                );
              } else if (snapshot.data == Event.Failed) {
                return AlertDialog(
                  scrollable: true,
                  content: Column(
                    children: [
                      Icon(
                        Icons.cancel,
                        color: Colors.red[800],
                        size: 300,
                      ),
                      Text(
                        "Invalid Fields",
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                );
              } else if (snapshot.data == Event.Error) {
                return AlertDialog(
                  scrollable: true,
                  content: Column(
                    children: [
                      Icon(
                        Icons.warning_rounded,
                        color: Colors.yellow[800],
                        size: 300,
                      ),
                      Text(
                        "Unknown Error",
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                );
              } else {
                return AlertDialog(
                  scrollable: true,
                  content: Column(
                    children: [
                      SizedBox(
                          height: 150,
                          width: 150,
                          child: CircularProgressIndicator(strokeWidth: 5.0)),
                      Text(
                        "Loading ",
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                );
              }
            });
      },
    );
```

stream controller

```
import 'dart:async';
enum Event{Loading,Failed,Error,Success}
class addEmpbloc{

  final _eventStreamController = StreamController<Event>.broadcast();


  StreamSink<Event> get eventSink => _eventStreamController.sink;
  Stream<Event>get eventStream => _eventStreamController.stream;

  void dispose(){
    _eventStreamController.close();
  }


}
```

```
void _reBuildTimer() {
    Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 3), (timer) {
      bloc.eventSink.add(Event.Success);
    });
  }
```

Instead of enum, u can use the data type of u r choice

Comment: Thanks , but this is a different case .Anyway to  change parameters  in  build(context) ?